# Network request using Volley and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am comfortable in using the Networking Api `Volley`. I am little bit confused that how things should go when I want to return the response to the `Caller Activity`. I can be done in two ways:

**1:** Initiate the `Volley` request and send the response to the caller via `sendBroadcast`

**2:** Run the `AsyncTask`, and then from `doInBackground` initiate the `Volley Synchronous` request like

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null, future, future);
requestQueue.add(request);
JSONObject response = future.get();
```

And then return this response to the `Caller` from `onPostExecute`

*Can anyone please guide which is the best approach among these two? or There is any other good approach while implementing such behavior?*

Example of such behavior is `Login Activity`, you initiate the login request and server returns the encrypted password and some other information which you want to save at your end.

Comment: Why are you using AsyncTask when you could be using Volley's Response.Listener instead? What do you mean by "Caller Activity"?

Comment: Volley response is received from background thread and in onResponse you don't know which activity to send the response, instead you will use sendBroadcast to send the result. Right?

Comment: It sounds like sendBroadcast() would work for the situation you are describing. However, if you are trying to return the JSONObject to the activity that started the current activity (as you would for a modal login screen), finishing the activity with a result might be a simpler way to solve the problem.